# ivar declarations in the .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a self taught iOS developer so this may be a concept I am missing. I have always put all my properties and iVar declarations in the .h (interface) file. I recently have been making modifications to projects other people have done and I am finding that say you have

```
MyMainViewController.h
MyMainViewController.m
```

They have nothing in `MyMainViewController.h` only an `@interface` declaration and declaring any delegates.

All the property and iVar declarations appear to be in the `MyMainViewController.m` 
looking something like this:

```
@interface MyMainViewController()

@property ….
```

Is this just a syntactical preference or is their some advantage to declaring an interface within the implementation (.m) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping property declaration within the implementation file effectively makes them private (unavailable outside of the implementation file). I guess that's the point.

As for the syntax, `@interface MyMainViewController()` is a declaration of an unnamed Objective-C category.

Comment: Aaahhh ok. That explains it.